# How to find out if a field is instanceof a type via reflection?

Tags: java, reflection

I want to find out via reflection if a field is an instance of some type `T`.

Lets say I have an object `o`. Now I want to know if it has any fields which are instance of `T`. I can get all fields with:

```
o.getClass().getFields();
```

I can get the type of the field with:

```
field.getType();
```

But now I want to know if this type or any supertype equals `T`. Do I have to call `getSuperclass()` recursively to be sure to check all supertypes?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You have to use [isAssignableFrom](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29).

Comment: Also look at isInstance, in the same documentation.

Answer (score 66):

The rather baroquely-named `Class.isAssignableFrom` is what you're after.  I usually end up having to read the javadoc to make sure I get it the right way around:

> Determines if the class or interface
> represented by this Class object is
> either the same as, or is a superclass
> or superinterface of, the class or
> interface represented by the specified
> Class parameter. It returns true if
> so; otherwise it returns false. If
> this Class object represents a
> primitive type, this method returns
> true if the specified Class parameter
> is exactly this Class object;
> otherwise it returns false.
>
> Specifically, this method tests
> whether the type represented by the
> specified Class parameter can be
> converted to the type represented by
> this Class object via an identity
> conversion or via a widening reference
> conversion.

For example:

```
public class X {
    
   public int i;

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Class<?> myType = Integer.class;
      Object o = new X();
      
      for (Field field : o.getClass().getFields()) {
         if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(myType)) {
            System.out.println("Field " + field + " is assignable from type " + o.getClass());
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: `Integer.TYPE;` should be `Integer.class;`

Answer (score 16):

If you want to compare the field type of a custom class you should try this,
use .class because only primitive types has .TYPE.

`if(field.getType().isAssignableFrom(**YOURCLASS.class**)){}`

Answer (score 0):

In case of `NullPointerException`, you can use [org.springframework.util.TypeUtils#isAssignable(java.lang.reflect.Type, java.lang.reflect.Type)](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/4.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/TypeUtils.html#isAssignable-java.lang.reflect.Type-java.lang.reflect.Type-) instead of [java.lang.Class#isAssignableFrom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29)