# Java: How to check if a Field is of type java.util.Collection

Tags: java, reflection, types

I have a utility method that goes through various classes and recursively retrieves the fields. I want to check if that field is a Collection.
Here is some sample code:

```
void myMethod(Class<?> classToCheck)

Field[] fields = classToCheck.getDeclaredFields();

for(Field field:fields)
{
   // check if field if a Collection<?>

}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Do you want to test whether the declared type of the field is an implementation of Collection, or whether the actual object referred to by the field in any given object implements Collection? The two results would differ if a) the Field was declared as Object, but an object implementing Collection was assigned to it, or b) the Field was declared as Collection (or a descendant) but it was null.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto find out if a field is instanceof a type via reflection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262322/howto-find-out-if-a-field-is-instanceof-a-type-via-reflection)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

```
if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {

}
```

Comment: @DJClayworth nope, it returns `Class<?>`. Check the javadoc

Comment: @DJClayworth, [the documentation that proves you wrong is pretty easy to google](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType()).

Comment: @user979467 I just tested it, it works.  Maybe you are doing something else wrong?

Comment: @Bozho My apologies, I found documentation that said it returned Type. Don't know where I found it now, so I'll just withdraw the comment.

Comment: Make sure you use the Correct Import for Collection. Shouldn't be from the org.hibernate package by mistake.

Comment: And how do you actually iterate over that collection?

Answer (score 8):

You should use `Class.isAssignableFrom`:

```
if (Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
    ...
```

Comment: isAssignableFrom takes a Class, where getType() returns a Type

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`getType()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29) method

```
Field field =  ...;
if ( Collection.class.isAssignableFrom( field.getType() ) ){
  //do something with your collection
}
```

Comment: nope, that's not it. This will get the class that owns the field, rather than the field type

Comment: Indeed. I just noticed my mistake by actually reading the javadoc. So far relying on my memory. Corrected my answer

Answer (score 1):

//This execute if

```
 List<String> cashType = split(" ,AlL ");
 if(cashType instanceof Collection){
     System.out.println("cashType instanceof Collection");
 }else{
     System.out.println("cashType is not instanceof Collection");
 }
```

//This executes else

```
List<String> cashType = split(" ,AlL ");
 if(cashType instanceof Hashtable){
     System.out.println("cashType instanceof Collection");
 }else{
     System.out.println("cashType is not instanceof Collection");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(Field field:fields) { // check if field if a Collection
  Object myInstance = field.get(classInstance); 
    // where classInstance is the instance in which the fields is stored
    if(myInstance instanceof Collection) {
        //Do your thing
    }
}
```

This tests whether the actual object referred to by the field 'field' (of the object classInstance) implements Collection. If you want to tests whether the declared type of Field implements Collection then that will be different.

Comment: Then it isn't an instanceof Collection. instanceof handles this case correctly, I believe.

Comment: New edits make it clear this wasn't the question the OP was asking, but I'll leave this here as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getType()` in the following way:

```
if (field.getType().equals(Collection.class) {
    // Do something
}
```

This will only work if the field is declared as a `Collection`. It will not work if the field is a subtype of Collection, such as `List` or `Vector`.