# Compare Java Type to Class

Tags: java, reflection

I'm having a little trouble putting this simple example together.

With reflection, I can get a type of a certain declared field. But how do I compare this to a known class?

What I'm trying to do is something like:

```
Type t = myField.getType();
if (t.equals(MyOwnClass.class)) {
    // Now I know myField is of type MyOwnClass
}
```

Comment: maybe you can instead compare t.getClassName() or something similar.  would be a string comparison.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262322/howto-find-out-if-a-field-is-instanceof-a-type-via-reflection

Comment: use instanceof operator

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850951/checking-a-class-type-class-is-equal-to-some-other-class-type

Comment: I think, the code you wrote should be working fine

Comment: I can confirm my example works. I didn't think it would, but apparently I was spot on.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, you already found the correct answer, with only a bit of commenting needed. The other answer is just wrong.

Firstly, `getType()` returns a `Class<?>` reference, with a `Class` class implementing a `Type` interface; using a `Type` variable for a `isAssignableFrom()` call is wrong for two reasons:

- `Type` doesn't have `isAssignableFrom()` method
- `Class#isAssignableFrom()` requires a `Class<?>` parameter, not a `Type` parameter

Simply put, you probably *shouldn't* compare a `Class`/`Type` this way, because you're hiding the relevant typing and requiring unnecessary casts. On the other hand, you just upcasted the `Class<?>` reference to `Type` reference, and since `equals()` called on `Class` (even casted to `Type`) actually calls `Object#equals()`, it simply calls

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

straight from `Object.java`, as `Class.java` doesn't override it in any way.

Secondly, you *could* do what you already done, but is one of the proper ways:

```
if ( myField.getType() == MyOwnClass.class ) {
    // Now I know myField is of type MyOwnClass
} // note that this requires a single ClassLoader to be used! Two ClassLoaders could in theory load one class with two separate Class instances
```

alternatively, you could

```
if ( myField.getType().getCanonicalName().equals( MyOwnClass.class.getCanonicalName() ) {
    // Now I know myField is of type MyOwnClass
} // note that this uses a name comparison, not a class comparison
```

or even

```
if ( myField.getType().isAssignableFrom( MyOwnClass.class )) {
  // Now I know MyOwnClass objects can be cast to myField.getType() safely
} // note: they are either equal or MyOwnClass is a subclass of myField.getType()
```

tl;dr Using `equals()` on a `Class` object is unnecessary here, as two equal classes have to be `==` anyway, as is casting to `Type` - still, the answer you provided in your question is a working solution indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the function

```
isAssignableFrom()
```

to determine this. Note, that also inherited classes are allowed.

```
Type t = myField.getType();
if (t.isAssignableFrom(MyOwnClass.class)) {
    // Now I know myField is of type MyOwnClass
}
```

Comment: Well, your example doesn't work as is because Type is an interface implemented by Class, so I need to get from t to the class it represents. Would casting `(Class)t` suffice?

Comment: You may want to inverse the check; e.g.: MyOwnClass.class.isAssignableFrom(t), allowing MyOwnClass to be checked for an implementation of t